# Strange Issue with NSURL with Xocode6.1

Tags: ios, nsstring, xcode6, nsurl

I have a strange issue with `Xcode6.1`

_mainURl is my  ' ServerLink '

service is ' GetUserById '

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_mainURl,service];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

When I append two strings and Create a url with `NSURL`, url getting  `'null'`

But, When I directly given the server link followed by serviceName I can generate URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ServerLink/GetUserById"]];
```

Comment: try to use encoding on NSString

Comment: what's the content of `str`? Add `NSLog(@"%@", str);`

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: both two parameters and appended string value having value but, after generating url will be null

Comment: what is your  _mainURl , service string??

Comment: there is something wrong with your _mainURl and service as ii have tried this code in my xcode this is working fine

Comment: @VineeshTP you can get the string value in Str parameter but it should be valid URL String if the str is not valid, URLWithString: give you null result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have written, the string you format would be "ServerLinkGetUserById". That is different to the string you enter manually of @"ServerLink/GetUserById".

Try updating your format to be:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_mainURl,service];
```

Comment: I have tried this. When i do like this the url will be null

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_mainURl,service];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

don't you try like this ??

i think i am not sure exact what issue having you but as your bellow description, i think you left this part

Comment: I have tried this.  When i do like this the url will be null

Comment: could you please paste your original link here with post data  ??

Comment: It is my server link. I can Append 2 string that is fine but, after try to generate url getting null

Comment: Can you NSLog the value of str to verify it is @"ServerLink/GetUserById"

Comment: I have checked the code and it's fine. I suspect the issue is that your variables are not what you expect.

Comment: exactly, this is not a big issue what you thought, Please NSLog once and see what this will be print, cross check once again what you append is that right ??

Comment: @GaryRiches : "NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str]; " only having issue , the url getting null

Comment: @Bineesh, yep, I understand that. It's because "str" isn't what you think.Right off the bat its @"ServerLinkGetUserById" based on your format... but even that works. So I'm guessing that _mainURl or service isn;t what you think. Log the str.

Comment: @GaryRiches str having the value  "ServerLink/GetUserById "

Comment: That's a different value than to what the code above will return. Is the code now different?